# How can I make my ruby remove_duplicates(nums) algorithm more efficient

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

This is the coding challenge: Given a sorted array, remove the duplicates in-place such that each element appear only once and return the new length.

Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

My answer

```
def remove_duplicates(nums)

    hash = {}

    nums.each do |num|
      if hash[num].nil?
        hash[num] = 1
      end 
      if hash[num] = 1
        i = nums.index(num)
        nums.delete(num)
        nums.insert(i, num)
      end 
    end

    nums.length    
end
```

On leetcode my answer passes 160/161 test cases. But I am receiving a "Time limit exceeded" error. The error says that my answer is not efficient enough to solve the last test case.

I am a beginner and I'm looking for advice on how to make my answer more efficient (in ruby)!

Comment: Did you try just `nums.uniq!.size`?

Comment: Or even `(nums.uniq! || nums).size` because Array#uniq! returns nil if there aren't duplicates

Comment: The `delete` operations here are going to be pretty punishing in terms of performance.

Comment: Yes you are right! I was trying to avoid using built in methods that do ALL the work for me, but I think this is a great alternative

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use one of the built-in methods being suggested in the comments, one algorithm to do this in O(n) Time and O(1) Space is to use 2 indexes to loop through the array. The first one is going to be the index at which you last inserted a unique value into, the second one is the index of the element you are currently looking at. The key to this is that the `nums` array is sorted, so you only need to set the next value if it's greater than the current value. It can't be less (because sorted) and if it's equal to the last value you inserted, it's not unique. For instance:

```
nums = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10]
def remove_duplicates(nums)
  return 0 if !nums || nums.empty?
  insertion_index = 0

  1.upto(nums.length - 1) do |lookup_index|
    if nums[lookup_index] > nums[insertion_index]
      insertion_index += 1

      nums[insertion_index] = nums[lookup_index]
    end
  end

  # nums is currently:
  # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10]
  insertion_index + 1
end

remove_duplicates(nums)
```

Your return value is going to be the `insertion_index + 1`, because the `insertion_index` is the index at which the last unique value was inserted, so the length of an array is the final index + 1.

It's been a while since I've done a leetcode problem, but I seem to remember in questions like these where you need to resize an array in place, just leaving everything at the end as whatever was the way to go (We're in Ruby, but there are a lot of submissions in other languages where it isn't as easy to just resize arrays in place). Feel free to remove the values from the end (in place, per the instructions) if you want/but if all you need is the length of the unique array, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Differences of a few milliseconds aren't really meaningful. Try and run on much larger arrays for more iterations so you can see differences of like +/- seconds, and even better, express those as percentages. Ruby's internal `Benchmark` tool usually gives a pretty good breakdown.

Comment: Another thing to fix here is you should truncate the resulting array. Right now it leaves traces of the original data just lumped in there.

Comment: _"if all you need is the length of the unique array, it shouldn't be necessary [to truncate the array]"_ – if all you need is the length, you shouldn't modify the array. But if you do, leave it in a clean state. Otherwise, this is a neat approach.